# html table disappears when it is inside ajaxToolkit:TabPanel

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I used tablesorter plugin to sort an HTML TABLE.
When I put the table inside ajaxToolkit TabPanel then the header of the HTML Table disappears. ( When the HTML table is outside of the ajaxToolkit TabPanel it is o.k.)

```
    $(window).load(function () {  
        $('#ConnectedActivitiesTable').append("<thead> <tr> <th> profix </th> <th> prog </th> <th> loc </th> <th> pop </th> <th> div </th> </tr> </thead>");
        $("#ConnectedActivitiesTable").tablesorter();
    });

   <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" ActiveTabIndex="0" Width="100%"  height="300px" runat="server">
        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="AboutTab" HeaderText="about" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table id="TabsContainer" class="tabsContainer">
```

.
.
.
.

```
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

        <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="RelatedPrograms" HeaderText="connected" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                   <table id="ConnectedActivitiesTable" runat="server" class=tbl > </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

The problem is with ConnectedActivitiesTable
ConnectedActivitiesTable is filled in c# codebehind

```
    public static void ShowTable(List<ActivityAllDetails> activityList, HtmlTable htmlTable)
    {
        htmlTable.Visible = true;
        HtmlTableCell cell;
        HtmlTableRow row;

        foreach (var activity in activityList)
        {
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.Attributes.Add("dir", "ltr");
            cell.InnerText = activity.ProphixNo;
            row = new HtmlTableRow();
            row.Controls.Add(cell);

            cell = new HtmlTableCell();

            cell.InnerHtml = "<a href=Tabs.aspx?" + QryStringKeys.ACTIVITY_ID + "=" + activity.ActivityId + ">" + (activity.Prg2NameHeb != null ? activity.Prg2NameHeb : activity.Prg2Name) + " </a>";
            row.Controls.Add(cell);

            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = activity.LocationDesc;
            row.Controls.Add(cell);


            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = activity.PopulationDesc;
            row.Controls.Add(cell);

            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = activity.DivisionDesc;
            row.Controls.Add(cell);


            htmlTable.Controls.Add(row);
        } 

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

When putting the HTML table in the ajaxToolkit:TabPanel, Ajax changes the ID of the HTML table (visible in sourcecode). Therefore the HTML table has to be refered by the new ID or by using a class for refering.

```
<table id="ConnectedActivitiesTable" runat="server"  class="ConnectedActivitiesTableCss">

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function () { 
            $('.ConnectedActivitiesTableCss').append("<thead> <tr> <th> profix </th> <th> prg </th> <th> loc</th> <th> pop</th> <th> div</th> </tr> </thead>");            
       });
</script>
```

I changed iD-specifier `$('#ConnectedActivitiesTable')`
to class-specifier `$('.ConnectedActivitiesTableCss')`